# How do I load a PHP library without Composer? (eg. wrench)

Tags: php

How do I load a PHP library without using Composer? I want to load the [wrench](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench) library. I've searched Stack Overflow and none of the solutions work for me. I am not using a PHP framework, just plain php files.

Comment: ...after all, what are the benefits of **not** using Composer?

Comment: I think library is dependent on psr module if that's the case you've to use composer

Comment: Is it just Composer or do you don´t want to use any package manager?

Comment: I don't want to use any package manager.

Comment: I've updated my question now to make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @jereon I've updated my question to make it unique and not a duplicate.